Simple Krishna mantras and Upasana methods for householders
Lord Krishna is my kula devta. I want to get the blessings of the lord. How can I as a house holder worship lord Krishna to get his mercy ? What are his mantras that I can chant ? What bhogas can I offer to please the deity (according to shastras) ? Is chanting the ashttotara shatanama of Krishna help in this regard ?

You should go with hare krishna mahamantra or Radha naam jaap because it is not appropriate (refrain from it) to chant or play on speaker mantras with aum and namo/namah and you should follow the book called vaishnav etiquette for your resolving doubts


Vaishnav etiquettes
https://www.krishnatemple.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Vaisnava-Etiquette-Manual.pdf
